# Upper bounding the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of an indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying Zygmund's *Measure and Integral* book and he defines the *Hardy-Littlewood maximal function* of $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as
$$f^{*}(x) = \sup \frac{1}{|Q|}\int_{Q}|f(y)|dy$$
where the supremum is taken over all $Q$ with edges parallel to the coordinate axes and center $x$. (|Q| is the Lebesgue measure of the cube)

It further states that

> For any measurable $E$,
> $$\chi_{E}^{*}(x) = \sup\left\{\frac{|E\cap Q|}{|Q|}: \text{$Q$ has center x}\right\}$$
> If $E$ is bounded and $Q^{x}$ denotes the smallest cube with center $x$ containing $E$, then
> $$\frac{|E\cap Q^{x}|}{|Q^{x}|} = \frac{|E|}{|Q^{x}|}$$
> It follows that there are positive constants $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ such that
> $$c_{1}\frac{|E|}{|x|^{n}} \leq \chi_{E}^{*}(x)\leq c_{2}\frac{|E|}{|x|^{n}}$$

---

I don't know how to find such $c_{2}$ such that $\chi_{E}^{*}(x)\leq c_{2}\frac{|E|}{|x|^{n}}$ as in the above statement.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How can the lower bound be true?  We have that $\chi_E^* \le 1$, so what happens as $x \to 0$?